# java.sql.SQLException: No such table : Member_Registration

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlitemanager

I am using Netbeans IDE and Sqlite add on from firefox.

Only when I use Login table code successfully run but while I trying to use another tables "No such table " error is coming . I didn't get what is going on? Whether there is any error in my connection code or something else.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        try{
           String id1=txtnm.getText();
           String nm=String.valueOf(txtpwd.getPassword());
           Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:F://MYDB/ADGSS.sqlite"))
         {

                PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from Member_Registration where UserName1=? and Password1=?");
                pst.setString(1,id1);
                pst.setString(2,nm);
                ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    con.close(); 
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not registered user ! please try again later !!");
                }
            }          
       }
       catch(Exception ee){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ee);
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: when you login is Member_Registration table registered in your DB ADGSS.sqlite?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Member_Registration and Login both tables is in ADGSS database.

Comment: The evidence shows they are not.

Comment: How to register table in database ?

Comment: I was getting the same error. Either there could be a type and the name of the table in the query might be different to the name saved in the sqlite manager or the path F://MYDB/ADGSS.sqlite might not be the correct.